# recursive sql assignment until quantity runs out

Tags: sql, db2

I am try to perform a recursive join assignment of License ID numbers until quantity "runs out" using a CTE style, union all recursive statement, but I can't quite get the peices to work together.

The problem I keep running into is that many licenses can cover 1 instance, so when I join to the licenses table I get many rows.  Any suggestions would be most welcome.

```
TABLE: INSTALLEDSW      
INSTALLEDSW_ID  PRODUCT_ID  PRODUCT_NAME
200             1000        MY SOFTWARE
201             1000        MY SOFTWARE
202             1000        MY SOFTWARE
203             1000        MY SOFTWARE
204             1000        MY SOFTWARE
205             1000        MY SOFTWARE
206             1000        MY SOFTWARE
207             1000        MY SOFTWARE
208             1000        MY SOFTWARE


TABLE:  LICENSE          
LICENSE_ID  PRODUCT_ID  LICENSE_NAME    QUANTITY
100         1000        MY LICENSE      1 
101         1000        MY LICENSE      5 
102         1000        MY LICENSE      1


Desired Result Set  
INSTALLEDSW_ID      LICENSE_ID
200                 100
201                 101
202                 101
203                 101
204                 101
205                 101
206                 102
207                 (null)
208                 (null)
```

Comment: Can you please show the query that doesn't quite work?

Comment: How does the `installedsw` and the `license` table relate?  Is it just by the `product_id`?  How does `INSTALLEDSW_ID` relate to `LICENSE_ID`?

Comment: INSTALLEDSW and LICENSE tables are joined by PRODUCTID.  So basically LICENSE.PRODUCTID says 'this license can cover product XYZ'.

Comment: Interesting problem, but you don't need recursive CTEs to solve it.  What database are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a recursive CTE for this.  Instead, you need a cumulative sum on the licenses to get quantity ranges.  The final result is simply a join after that.

Let me assume you are using Postgres, SQL Server 2012, or Oracle, which support this.  In other databases, you can do the necessary calculations correlated subqueries instead of window functions.

```
select l.*, SumQTy - Qty + 1 as StartQTY, QTY as EndQTY
from (select l.*,
             sum(quantity) over (partition by product_id order by license_id) as Sumqty
      from license l
     ) l
```

So, this license is the valid one between the StaartQTY and the EndQTY.

Next, you need to apply these to your users.  For that, we use `row_number()` to enumerate the installed:

```
with l as (
     select l.*, SumQTy - Qty + 1 as StartQTY, QTY as EndQTY
     from (select l.*,
                  sum(quantity) over (partition by product_id order by license_id) as Sumqty
           from license l
          ) l
    )
select i.installedsw_id, l.licence_id
from (select i.*,
             row_number() over (partition by product_id order by installedsw_id) as num
      from installedsw i
     ) i left outer join
     l
     on i.installedsw_id = l.installedsw_id and
        i.num between l.startQty and l.endQty
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid recursion whenever possible, and for that matter, cumulative sums (they're both *very* expensive).  Make yourself an integers table (a "utility knife" you will use often):

```
CREATE TABLE integers (n smallint primary key clustered)
INSERT integers SELECT TOP 1000 row_number() over (order by o.id) from sysobjects o cross join sysobjects
```

Then this becomes a whole lot easier when you:

```
   join (select * from LICENSE, integers where n <= quantity) LICENSE on...
```

Then rank each table, join on the rank, and set the License_ID when rank <= #ofLicenses.  (I'm not familiar with DB2, but you'll probably have to simulate the ranking in temp tables.)

```
SELECT ISW.INSTALLEDSW_ID, LICENSE_ID = case when LIC.rank <= [# of licenses] then LIC.LICENSE_ID else null end
FROM (     select *, rank = row_number over (order by INSTALLEDSW_ID) from INSTALLEDSW) ISW
    JOIN ( select *, rank = row_number over (order by LICENSE_ID)
           from (select * from LICENSE, integers where n <= quantity) t ) LIC on LIC.productid_id = ISW.productid AND LIC.rank = ISW.rank
```

Comment: Unfortunately, creating a new table is not an option for me.  Could I use a CTE table/temp table for this?

Comment: @bwperrin . . . Why do you think cumulative sums are more expensive than `row_number()`?  In databases that support them using window functions, the performance should be pretty close to identical.

Comment: @user1527312 - you could use a simple recursive CTE to create an on-the-fly numbers table.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse, could you give an example?  This is what I was struggling with.  Also, would a CTE "auto numbering" table perform better than "row_number over"?